# JSON Not Returning Any Results

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid

I am building a website based on MVC with a SQL database & ASP.Net 4

Not sure what I am missing but I am trying to display a table that is updateable using the Kendo UI framework.

Please see the below

**Controller:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Reads the available products to provide data for the Kendo Grid
/// </summary>
/// <returns>All available products as JSON</returns>
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Read(int take, int skip, IEnumerable<Sort> sort, Kendo.DynamicLinq.Filter filter)
{
    using (var db = new SC_NewEntities12())
    {
        var result = db.SC_Opportunities
            .OrderBy(p => p.CUST_IntranetDate_093808085) // EF requires ordered IQueryable in order to do paging
            // Use a view model to avoid serializing internal Entity Framework properties as JSON
            .Select(p => new UpdateViewModel
            {
                MANAGEUSERID = p.MANAGEUSERID,
                CUST_Customer_070539405 = p.CUST_Customer_070539405,
                CUST_Make_093929971 = p.CUST_Make_093929971,
                CUST_Model_093950750 = p.CUST_Model_093950750,
                CUST_CurrentSupplier_100623404 = p.CUST_CurrentSupplier_100623404,
                CUST_CurrentDealer_100741601 = p.CUST_CurrentDealer_100741601,
                CUST_UpdateFromSupplier_010859867 = p.CUST_UpdateFromSupplier_010859867,
                CUST_UpdateFromSupplierDate_010930291 = p.CUST_UpdateFromSupplierDate_010930291,
                CUST_CarEstimatedDeliveryDate_121235253 = p.CUST_CarEstimatedDeliveryDate_121235253,
                CUST_IntranetDate_093808085 = p.CUST_IntranetDate_093808085,
                Link2Contact = p.Link2Contact,
                Link2Opportunity = p.Link2Opportunity,
                STAGEID = p.STAGEID,
                E_Mail = p.E_Mail,
                STATUS = p.STATUS
            })
            .ToDataSourceResult(take, skip, sort, filter);

        return Json(result);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<IntranetEF6.Models.SC_Opportunities>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Update JSON Test";
}

<h2>Update JSON Test</h2>

<div id="clientsDb">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<IntranetEF6.Models.SC_Opportunities>()
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.CUST_IntranetDate_093808085).Title("Intranet Date").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
            columns.Bound(p => p.MANAGEUSERID).Title("Sales Person").ClientTemplate("#if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'c37ac75b-286d-430a-af50-8d3dffa8b1ee') " + "{#<div>Daren</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == '1acb3e5a-81ed-4cb4-a68f-094939f0efa4') " + "{#<div>David</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == '739f07c5-defe-4395-a93e-51adc7f410ff') " + "{#<div>Dee</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'ca3dfb36-0efe-43df-9801-7602a0b112ae') " + "{#<div>James</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'a88a8884-3133-4ca5-bf82-cd4b87eb12cb') " + "{#<div>Jamie</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'e317009f-cde0-49c2-80dc-da3ce9c40b3b') " + "{#<div>Mark</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == '58d0e41d-904b-4c93-8ac7-424b5370fe2e') " + "{#<div>Paul</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == '28457a43-ebc2-490f-b423-db1fdaa3d3b5') " + "{#<div>Richard</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'c5474c7e-a829-4a0e-af07-8e0614bb3cc4') " + "{#<div>Rowan</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'fac58484-8b20-4b97-8eb8-5d060db84d93') " + "{#<div>Russell</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'b3fc40ae-b547-4f59-b651-ba30dbe60d1a') " + "{#<div>Sam Bryan</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == '8fb9c8b4-bfe2-42ce-aa5b-d2cbbf96f186') " + "{#<div>Santi</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'dc8cd950-d4cc-4c5f-9ab0-867dbf13d61b') " + "{#<div>Shane</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == '42182f43-f8a3-41d8-bcac-70fcc9942027') " + "{#<div>Steve</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'e93c7603-b49e-4f53-acdb-9847ba407efa') " + "{#<div>Yasir</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'd8c83978-4aeb-49a8-8b6c-f3e5dbba4288') " + "{#<div>Jenny</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'c48c2aec-cdf2-427b-a18b-ce6e7499fa86') " + "{#<div>Harry</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == '6efc7514-d8ef-446e-85b8-0246b168d5cc') " + "{#<div>Sam Malik</div>#} #");
            columns.Bound(p => p.CUST_Customer_070539405).Title("Customer");
            columns.Bound(p => p.CUST_Make_093929971).Title("Make");
            columns.Bound(p => p.CUST_Model_093950750).Title("Model");
            columns.Bound(p => p.CUST_CurrentSupplier_100623404).Title("Funder");
            columns.Bound(p => p.CUST_CurrentDealer_100741601).Title("Dealer");
            columns.Bound(p => p.CUST_CarEstimatedDeliveryDate_121235253).Title("Order From Date").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
            columns.Bound(p => p.CUST_UpdateFromSupplier_010859867).Title("Update From Supplier");
            columns.Bound(p => p.CUST_UpdateFromSupplierDate_010930291).Title("Update From Supplier Date").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
            columns.Bound(p => p.Link2Contact).Title("Act! Contact").ClientTemplate(@"<a href=#=Link2Contact#>Open Contact</a>");
            columns.Bound(p => p.Link2Opportunity).Title("Act! Opp").ClientTemplate(@"<a href=#=Link2Opportunity#>Open Opp</a>");
        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
        .Scrollable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(400)
            .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Grid"))
        )
    )
</div>
```

Comment: Using a tool like Fiddler or your browsers dev tools: is any data being returned by the action method?

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for the response. I am not sure this is what you meant but I have taken a look at the console. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Titles' of undefined
http://localhost:64537/Grid/Read Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: So, when the grid tries to get data it cannot find anything at the URL. If you put a breakpoint on the `Read` method you'll find it is never hit. You need to debug deeper. For a start the lack of any query parameters on your URL means it will not match your action (try making the action's parameters nullable).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  Try modifying your action method to have the following signature.  You need to also be using the `Kendo.Mvc.UI` namespace.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest dataSourceRequest)
{
 using (var db = new SC_NewEntities12())
    {
        var result = db.SC_Opportunities
            .OrderBy(p => p.CUST_IntranetDate_093808085) // EF requires ordered IQueryable in order to do paging
            // Use a view model to avoid serializing internal Entity Framework properties as JSON
            .Select(p => new UpdateViewModel
            {
                MANAGEUSERID = p.MANAGEUSERID,
                CUST_Customer_070539405 = p.CUST_Customer_070539405,
                CUST_Make_093929971 = p.CUST_Make_093929971,
                CUST_Model_093950750 = p.CUST_Model_093950750,
                CUST_CurrentSupplier_100623404 = p.CUST_CurrentSupplier_100623404,
                CUST_CurrentDealer_100741601 = p.CUST_CurrentDealer_100741601,
                CUST_UpdateFromSupplier_010859867 = p.CUST_UpdateFromSupplier_010859867,
                CUST_UpdateFromSupplierDate_010930291 = p.CUST_UpdateFromSupplierDate_010930291,
                CUST_CarEstimatedDeliveryDate_121235253 = p.CUST_CarEstimatedDeliveryDate_121235253,
                CUST_IntranetDate_093808085 = p.CUST_IntranetDate_093808085,
                Link2Contact = p.Link2Contact,
                Link2Opportunity = p.Link2Opportunity,
                STAGEID = p.STAGEID,
                E_Mail = p.E_Mail,
                STATUS = p.STATUS
            })
            .ToDataSourceResult(dataSourceRequest);

        return Json(result);
    }
}
```

Your action method only accepts HTTP POST.  Your data source configuration needs to be as follows:

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<IntranetEF6.Models.SC_Opportunities>()
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.CUST_IntranetDate_093808085).Title("Intranet Date").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
            columns.Bound(p => p.MANAGEUSERID).Title("Sales Person").ClientTemplate("#if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'c37ac75b-286d-430a-af50-8d3dffa8b1ee') " + "{#<div>Daren</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == '1acb3e5a-81ed-4cb4-a68f-094939f0efa4') " + "{#<div>David</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == '739f07c5-defe-4395-a93e-51adc7f410ff') " + "{#<div>Dee</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'ca3dfb36-0efe-43df-9801-7602a0b112ae') " + "{#<div>James</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'a88a8884-3133-4ca5-bf82-cd4b87eb12cb') " + "{#<div>Jamie</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'e317009f-cde0-49c2-80dc-da3ce9c40b3b') " + "{#<div>Mark</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == '58d0e41d-904b-4c93-8ac7-424b5370fe2e') " + "{#<div>Paul</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == '28457a43-ebc2-490f-b423-db1fdaa3d3b5') " + "{#<div>Richard</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'c5474c7e-a829-4a0e-af07-8e0614bb3cc4') " + "{#<div>Rowan</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'fac58484-8b20-4b97-8eb8-5d060db84d93') " + "{#<div>Russell</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'b3fc40ae-b547-4f59-b651-ba30dbe60d1a') " + "{#<div>Sam Bryan</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == '8fb9c8b4-bfe2-42ce-aa5b-d2cbbf96f186') " + "{#<div>Santi</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'dc8cd950-d4cc-4c5f-9ab0-867dbf13d61b') " + "{#<div>Shane</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == '42182f43-f8a3-41d8-bcac-70fcc9942027') " + "{#<div>Steve</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'e93c7603-b49e-4f53-acdb-9847ba407efa') " + "{#<div>Yasir</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'd8c83978-4aeb-49a8-8b6c-f3e5dbba4288') " + "{#<div>Jenny</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == 'c48c2aec-cdf2-427b-a18b-ce6e7499fa86') " + "{#<div>Harry</div>#} " + "if(data.MANAGEUSERID.toString() == '6efc7514-d8ef-446e-85b8-0246b168d5cc') " + "{#<div>Sam Malik</div>#} #");
            columns.Bound(p => p.CUST_Customer_070539405).Title("Customer");
            columns.Bound(p => p.CUST_Make_093929971).Title("Make");
            columns.Bound(p => p.CUST_Model_093950750).Title("Model");
            columns.Bound(p => p.CUST_CurrentSupplier_100623404).Title("Funder");
            columns.Bound(p => p.CUST_CurrentDealer_100741601).Title("Dealer");
            columns.Bound(p => p.CUST_CarEstimatedDeliveryDate_121235253).Title("Order From Date").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
            columns.Bound(p => p.CUST_UpdateFromSupplier_010859867).Title("Update From Supplier");
            columns.Bound(p => p.CUST_UpdateFromSupplierDate_010930291).Title("Update From Supplier Date").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
            columns.Bound(p => p.Link2Contact).Title("Act! Contact").ClientTemplate(@"<a href=#=Link2Contact#>Open Contact</a>");
            columns.Bound(p => p.Link2Opportunity).Title("Act! Opp").ClientTemplate(@"<a href=#=Link2Opportunity#>Open Opp</a>");
        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
        .Scrollable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(400)
            .Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Type(HttpVerbs.Post);
                    read.Action("Read", "Grid");
                })
        )
        )
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the response. This did not change anything I am afraid, it still has no items to display. It is strange because when I when using a normal HTML table without JSON, just returning it, it will load all the data in the model.

Comment: Unrelated - I just realized you were reporting from a Act! database.  Why not use the SDK? :)

Comment: Good eye! I have not worked with the SDK before and felt more comfortable this way, but am running into isuses this way too. Will take a look at it though. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: My apologies if I am being a nusiance here, but "No overload for method 'ToDataSourceResult' takes 1 argument"

Comment: What version of Kendo do you have?

Comment: I have version v2014.3.1316

Comment: Since 2012 this has worked, here are the different overloads for ToDataSourceResult that take one argument.    `public static DataSourceResult ToDataSourceResult(this DataTable dataTable, DataSourceRequest request);
        public static DataSourceResult ToDataSourceResult(this IEnumerable enumerable, DataSourceRequest request);
        public static DataSourceResult ToDataSourceResult(this IQueryable enumerable, DataSourceRequest request);`

Comment: Sorry, I added the using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions; reference and it now builds without error - though still no results.

Answer (score 0):

I moved around the kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js was at the bottom of the Kendo bundles, as per the troubleshooting on their site.

I then changed the read action to match the name of the controller which it was not;

.Read(read => read.Action("Read", "UpdateJSONTest").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))

I was getting confused because the Kendo samples say "Grid" I thought that I was meant to be using the name of the grid, not the controller.

Comment: Thank you all for help and responses though!

Comment: You didn't post your controller name, so I could only assume it was called "Grid".  The original HTTP Post issue I noticed would have still applied but it looks like you kept in the fix.